# Unable to retrieve injected IJSRuntime in Blazor Webassembly application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8.0 Blazor webassembly application. I'm trying to setup localization.

One of the localization configuration steps is to get `IJSRuntime` service for further invocation of a Javascript method.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                    .AddServerComponents();
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    builder.Services.AddLocalization();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
      .AddServerRenderMode();

    await app.SetDefaultCulture();
    await app.RunAsync();
}
```

The `SetDefaultCulture` extension method looks like this:

```
public static class WebAssemblyHostExtension
{
    public static async Task SetDefaultCulture(this WebApplication host)
    {
        var jsInterop = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>(); // Error is here
        var result = await jsInterop.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");
        CultureInfo culture;

        if (result != null)
            culture = new CultureInfo(result);
        else
            culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

But when I try to get `IJSRuntime` service by calling `GetRequiredService`, I get this error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime' from root provider.

Comment: How have you created your project? From CLI, from VS? which options did you choose? Which dotnet 8 SDK are you using?

Comment: My hunch is that IJSRuntime is not available before the app initiates (IJSRuntime represents the runtime environment of the webpage in which the Blazor app is being run. It *wont* exist before the app runs. Depending on where you are getting the culture setting, you can either make the call in OnInitializedAsync of every page or, if it is available as API, call it from a service and access it through DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicate that the `IJSRuntime` service cannot be resolved from the root provider. This is because `IJSRuntime` is a scoped service and cannot be directly accessed from the root provider. In the Blazor WebAssembly app, the `IJSRuntime` service is registered as a scoped service, which means it can only be resolved within a certain request scope. In a typical Blazor server-side or Blazor WebAssembly application, scoped services are available only during the handling of a single user interaction. To resolve this, you should access the `IJSRuntime` within a component or within a scoped environment. Once the operations within the scope are completed, remember to dispose of the scope.

Here is the code to manually create scope:

```
public static class WebAssemblyHostExtension
{
    public static async Task SetDefaultCulture(this WebApplication host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var jsInterop = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
            var result = await jsInterop.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");
            CultureInfo culture;

            if (result != null)
                culture = new CultureInfo(result);
            else
                culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
    }
}
```